# Is it possible to add to the qt project a qml support widget on linux embedded?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to add a qml to large qt widget application (called appX in this question) for linux embedded.
If I run some qt examples on target device everything is good, but while I try to run appX with qml I got this:  `module "QtQuick" is not installed` .
appX is running on qt 5.5.1. What I should do to get it works?

This is code which run the qml view in widget.

```
QDeclarativeView *qmlView = new QDeclarativeView;
qmlView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/testy/SrgAppsVersionsTest.qml"));
this->setGeometry(0, 0 , 1024 , 768);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(qmlView);
```

Comment: Do you have `QT += qml quick` in your .pro file?

Comment: Yes, I have it included.